# Valgrind is telling me that an array is freed, before the array is actually freed

Tags: c, valgrind, free

Valgrind is telling me that I'm trying to read an array after it's free'd. However, according to valgrind, the array is free'd two lines later than I'm trying to read it! I'm very confused.

Here is the valgrind error:

```
==21632== Invalid read of size 8
==21632==    at 0x400D73: hDump (Lex1.c:91)
==21632==    by 0x400B19: process (mainLex.c:66)
==21632==    by 0x400A7C: main (mainLex.c:41)
==21632==  Address 0x51f3490 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==21632==    at 0x4C29577: free (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21632==    by 0x400B7E: freeList (mainLex.c:81)
==21632==    by 0x400A88: main (mainLex.c:43)
==21632== 
==21632== Invalid read of size 1
```

Here is mainLex.c:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ncmd = 1;                   // Command number
    char *line;                     // Initial command line
    char *cmd;                      // Command after history expansion
    int status;                     // Status of expansion
    token *list;                    // Linked list of tokens in command
    void process (token *);
    void freeList (token *);

    for (;;)  {
    printf ("(%d)$ ", ncmd);                // Prompt for command
    if ((line = getLine(stdin)) == NULL)    // Read line
        break;                              // Break on end of file

    cmd = hExpand (line, &status);          // Expand line
    free (line);
    if (status > 0)                         // Substitution?
        fputs (cmd, stdout);                //   Print expanded line
    else if (status < 0)
        fputs ("substitution failed\n", stderr);

    list = lex (cmd);                       // Lex line into tokens
    free (cmd);
    if (list == NULL)                       // Empty token list?
        continue;

    hRemember (ncmd, list);                 // Remember command
    if (status >= 0)                        // No substitution error?
    process (list);                     //   Process token list (This is line 41)

    freeList (list);                        // Free token list (This is line 43)
    ncmd++;                                 // Adjust prompt
    }

    hClear();                                   // Free all storage
    return 0;
}

// -- PROCESS MODULE -------------------------------------------------------

// Print list of tokens LIST
void process(struct token *list)
{
    struct token *p;
    void freeList (token *);

    for (p = list;  p != NULL;  p = p->next) {  // Walk down linked list
    printf ("%s:%d ", p->text, p->type);    //   printing token and type
    }
    putchar ('\n');                             // Terminate line

    // history command dumps most recent 9 commands
    if (list && !strcmp (list->text, "history"))
    hDump(9); //Line 66

    // hclear command clears history
    else if (list && !strcmp (list->text, "hclear"))
    hClear();
}


// Free list of tokens LIST
void freeList (token *list)
{
    token *p, *pnext;
    for (p = list;  p;  p = pnext)  {
    pnext = p->next;
    free(p->text);
    free(p); //Line 81
    }
}
```

EDIT: getLine is a separate function in the #include part at the top that I didn't include. I've also added extra line numbers, and will include a minimal example in a second.

Also, here is the code for hDump: (llist is a global static data structure)

```
void hDump (int n)
{
    token *current;
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        if (llist->prev!=NULL)
        {
            llist=llist->prev;
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        llist=llist->nextcmd;
        printf("%6d ", llist->num);
        current=llist->cmmd;
        if (current == NULL)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s ", current->text);
        }
        while(current->next!=NULL) //Line 91
        {
            current=current->next;
            printf("%s ", current->text);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: where is `getLine` ?

Comment: Give us some minimal sample input that triggers the error, and point out with comments in the code which line is 81 etc.

Comment: show the code of `hDump` . That function doesn't take any pointer arguments which suggests maybe you are keeping static variables , or something.

Comment: I suspect some of your linked lists are not properly terminated with `NULL`.

Comment: Can we see llist definition and the code of lex()? Any chance that lex() uses llist and returns it as list?

Comment: lex() does not use llist. I suspect that I may have not properly terminated some linked list, thank you for the help.